# Get list of users addresses that minted native asset NFT

Tags: nft, native-assets, api, cardano-address

I would like to get a list of user addresses, that minted a native asset NFT. Is this possible? I do not want current holders of the NFT, but the original minting NFT holders.

Comment: Is a solution using `cardano-db-sync` acceptable?

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the https://blockfrost.io API:

Fist you need to get the asset id, I assume you already have this because you know which NFT you want to look up.

Then you would query all transactions of this asset using the `Cardano > Assets > Asset Transactions` API endpoint:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1{asset}~1transactions/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1transactions/get)

This returns a list of transactions, where this asset has been involved.

```json
[
  {
    "tx_hash": "8788591983aa73981fc92d6cddbbe643959f5a784e84b8bee0db15823f575a5b",
    "tx_index": 6,
    "block_height": 69,
    "block_time": 1635505891
  },
  {
    "tx_hash": "52e748c4dec58b687b90b0b40d383b9fe1f24c1a833b7395cdf07dd67859f46f",
    "tx_index": 9,
    "block_height": 4547,
    "block_time": 1635505987
  },
  {
    "tx_hash": "e8073fd5318ff43eca18a852527166aa8008bee9ee9e891f585612b7e4ba700b",
    "tx_index": 0,
    "block_height": 564654,
    "block_time": 1834505492
  }
]
```

Now you take the `tx_hash` of the transaction with the lowest `block_height` and query the `Cardano > Transactions > Transaction UTxOs` endpoint:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1txs~1{hash}~1utxos/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D%7E1utxos/get)

This will result in an object like this:

```json
{
  "hash": "1e043f100dce12d107f679685acd2fc0610e10f72a92d412794c9773d11d8477",
  "inputs": [ ... ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "address": "addr1q9ld26v2lv8wvrxxmvg90pn8n8n5k6tdst06q2s856rwmvnueldzuuqmnsye359fqrk8hwvenjnqultn7djtrlft7jnq7dy7wv",
      "amount": [
        {
          "unit": "lovelace",
          "quantity": "42000000"
        },
        {
          "unit": "b0d07d45fe9514f80213f4020e5a61241458be626841cde717cb38a76e7574636f696e",
          "quantity": "12"
        }
      ],
      "output_index": 0,
      "data_hash": "9e478573ab81ea7a8e31891ce0648b81229f408d596a3483e6f4f9b92d3cf710",
      "inline_datum": "19a6aa",
      "collateral": false,
      "reference_script_hash": "13a3efd825703a352a8f71f4e2758d08c28c564e8dfcce9f77776ad1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Go through the `outputs` of this object and find the one that contains your NFT in the list of `amount` objects. The `address` of this `output` is the original receiver of your NFT.